# EF 4.0 update uniqueidentifier

Tags: entity-framework, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to update a colum with datatype  uniqueidentifier using EF v4.0.
I am getting an error Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
is there any  workarounds for this issue.

thanks
Ben

Comment: This works if your property is `Guid` so you must have some problem in your code / mapping - you didn't mention anything about your code or mapping so we can hardly help you.

Answer (score 1):

uniqueidentifier  -> the value should use Guid type in c#

Comment: propery is marked as guid. I ran the query that was generated in sql server but gave the same error